# Play2 Framework Better solution

Tags: java, playframework-2.2

So I am doing an edit profile feature with Play! Framework (2.2.0);

I have this code

```
public static Result doEditProfile(){

        final User localUser = getLocalUser(session());

        Form<User> formData = editProfileForm.bindFromRequest();

        if (formData.hasErrors()) {
           return badRequest(views.html.editprofile.render(localUser, editProfileForm));
        } else {
            localUser.firstName = formData.field("firstName").value();
            localUser.lastName = formData.field("lastName").value();
            localUser.locale = formData.field("locale").value();
            localUser.gender = formData.field("gender").value();
            localUser.country = formData.field("country").value();
            localUser.save();
        }

        return redirect("/profile/edit");
    }
```

It works. But I want to know is there a better way of doing this ?

I have tried this things:

1)

```
public static Result doEditProfile(){

        final User localUser = getLocalUser(session());

        Form<User> formData = editProfileForm.bindFromRequest();

        if (formData.hasErrors()) {
           return badRequest(views.html.editprofile.render(localUser, editProfileForm));
        } else {
            User localUser = formData.get();
            localUser.save();
        }

        return redirect("/profile/edit");
    }
```

but this says that variable localUser is already defined.

2) also, I tried this

```
public static Result doEditProfile(){

        final User localUser = getLocalUser(session());

        Form<User> formData = editProfileForm.bindFromRequest();

        if (formData.hasErrors()) {
           return badRequest(views.html.editprofile.render(localUser, editProfileForm));
        } else {
            User updatedUser = formData.get();
            updatedUser.save();
        }

        return redirect("/profile/edit");
    }
```

but this code is creating a new user in the database.

I am new to Play so I am waiting for any advice. Thanks and sorry for my english

Comment: I like the 1st option. It might be more verbose that the other 2 (even if they would work), but it's very easy to see what's going on and to reason what are the side effects: updating those 5 fields, rather than the whole user object.

Answer (score 0):

Does your user have a unique id? If so, you could try the following:

```
updatedUser.setId(localUser.getId())
updatedUser.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Saw this example here:

[How to update an existing object in playframework 2.0.2? aka CRUD in 1.2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467503/how-to-update-an-existing-object-in-playframework-2-0-2-aka-crud-in-1-2-x)

... along the lines of what @mantithetical was saying.  Better to have an update method in your User class:

```
public static Result update(Long id) {
    Form<User> userForm = form(User.class).bindFromRequest();
    if(userForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(editForm.render(id, userForm));
    }
    userForm.get().update(id);
    ...
```

Just a matter of providing the unique id (note that also, we're relying on the id, rather than the entire user, when handling bad requests).  You can do that by adding a parameter to your controller in the routes file:

```
POST /update/:id                    controllers.doEditProfile(id: Long)
```

Then when you direct to your controller method, you have to pass that unique id in.